# C# Text Game Miscalculates Integer Subtraction?

Tags: c#, console

So I'm learning C#, and I'm trying to make a simple text based RPG, but when I run the character creation this keeps happening:

5 Points Left

Strength?

Input: 4

Point amount too high! Press Enter.

Here's The Code.

```
public static void Start()
{
    Console.Clear();
    int charcreatepts = 10;
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} Points Left", charcreatepts);
    Console.WriteLine ("Intelligence?");
    int CCPint1 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
    charcreatepts = charcreatepts - CCPint1;
    if (CCPint1 > charcreatepts) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Point amount too high! Press Enter.");
        Console.ReadLine ();
        Start ();
    }else{
        Console.Clear ();
            Console.WriteLine ("{0} Points Left", charcreatepts);
            Console.WriteLine ("Strength?");
            int CCPint2 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
            charcreatepts = charcreatepts - CCPint2;
            if (CCPint2 > charcreatepts) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Point amount too high! Press Enter.");
                Console.ReadLine ();
                Start ();
            }else{
                Console.Clear ();
                Console.WriteLine ("{0} Points Left", charcreatepts);
                Console.WriteLine ("Social Skills?");
                int CCPint3 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
                charcreatepts = charcreatepts - CCPint3;
                if (CCPint3 > charcreatepts) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Point amount too high! Press Enter.");
                    Console.ReadLine ();
                    Start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get it so if you want, you can use the 5 remaining points on in this case, strength, but for some reason I can't even use 4.

Comment: Are you making a full RPG for Console?

Comment: Simplifying into small methods does a great deal of work when debugging... Have a function that prints points left from parameter, then asks for new points into a different attribute (again, a string parameter), checks if it exceeds the points left (parameter), and returns the amount of points the user chose (-1 can indicate "too high"). This turns your `Start` function into something a LOT nicer.

Comment: Made an example here: http://pastebin.com/kv7iSuZb It can be simplified even more, but this should do. The main point is keeping it maintainable and readable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are subtracting too early. Given: `charcreatepts = charcreatepts - CCPint1`, and `charcreatepts = 5` and `CCPint1 = 4` then `charcreatepts = 5 - 4 = 1`

Then:

`if (CCPInt1 > charcreatepts) { ... }` would be `if (4 > 1) { ... }`

You should check if `CCPint1` is greater than `charcreatepts` *before* you try to calculate the new value.